# Bypass "Confirm Navigation" Dialog in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm having a problem in Google Chrome where I am prompted with that annoying "Confirm Navigation: Leave Page / Stay On Page" dialog when I am leaving my HTML page (I'm thinking it may have to do with the fact that my HTML page has executed some JavaScript code).

I have actually had a similar problem a month ago where Chrome wanted a confirmation upon page redirect using the `location.replace()` method, but this issue has already been resolved by adding `window.onbeforeunload=null` into the same function as the redirect code -- with many thanks to this forum :D

I'm not actually looking for anything on how to disable the feature in Chrome per se, but I am looking to bypass the dialog programmatically in JavaScript (preferrably not jQuery). Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this, perhaps when the page is leaving?

I have tried using the event trigger `window.onbeforeunload=null;`, but that does not seem to work. Thanks immensely in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had that problem with my HTML code.

The problem was related to the action parameter in the body of the `<form>` tag.

The original code was:
`<form action="" method="post"> Body Content < /form>`

I just removed the action parameter and got:

`<form method="post"> Body Content < /form>`